# splitting timestamp in to two rows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, amazon-redshift, generate-series

I have two timestamps in the table:

```
     usage_from      |     usage_till     
---------------------+--------------------
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:16:00
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:08:19
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 18:58:22
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:15:05
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:09:00
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:08:20
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:32:04
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 02:02:03
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 07:31:00
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 22:41:04
```

This I need to split into as below:

```
 usage_from      |     usage_till        
---------------------+-----------------------
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:16:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:08:19 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-10 02:00:00 
 2013-10-10 02:00:00 |  2013-10-10 18:58:22 -- splitted
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:15:05 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:09:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:08:20 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-09 23:32:04 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-10 02:00:00 
 2013-10-10 02:00:00 |  2013-10-10 02:02:03 -- splitted
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-10 02:00:00 
 2013-10-10 02:00:00 |  2013-10-10 07:31:00 -- splitted
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 |  2013-10-10 02:00:00 
 2013-10-10 02:00:00 |  2013-10-10 22:41:04 -- splitted
```

Here in the above example I have split the timestamp at 02:00:00.

After many trials I could split it as below, but couldn't split as different row.

```
     usage_from      |     usage_till      |     end_time_1      |     end_time_2      
---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:16:00 | 2013-10-09 23:16:00 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:08:19 | 2013-10-09 23:08:19 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 18:58:22 | 2013-10-10 02:00:00 | 2013-10-10 18:58:22 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:15:05 | 2013-10-09 23:15:05 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:09:00 | 2013-10-09 23:09:00 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:08:20 | 2013-10-09 23:08:20 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-09 23:32:04 | 2013-10-09 23:32:04 | 2013-10-11 02:00:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 02:02:03 | 2013-10-10 02:00:00 | 2013-10-10 02:02:03 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 07:31:00 | 2013-10-10 02:00:00 | 2013-10-10 07:31:00 
 2013-10-09 23:08:17 | 2013-10-10 22:41:04 | 2013-10-10 02:00:00 | 2013-10-10 22:41:04
```

Any idea how to do this? I have been struggling for the last few days.
I'm using Redshift 1.0.757 (based on PostgreSQL 8.02).

Comment: *"Im using PostgreSQL 8.0"*. Then why is this tagged MySQL? And really, 8.0? That's *ancient*. Upgrade *urgently*, assuming you're really using Pg 8.0, and not some fork/variant of PostgreSQL. Show `SELECT version()` output.

Comment: Version: `PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.757`

Comment: Redshift isn't exactly Postgres. Much less MySQL, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** <sup>1</sup> Redshift would support the basic form of `generate_series()`, this might work. At least this works in Postgres 8.3:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN split > 0 AND g = 0 THEN usage_from
            WHEN split > 0 AND g = 1 THEN usage_till::date + '2:0'::time
            ELSE usage_from END
     , CASE WHEN split > 0 AND g = 0 THEN usage_till::date + '2:0'::time
            WHEN split > 0 AND g = 1 THEN usage_till
            ELSE usage_till END
FROM  (
   SELECT * , generate_series(0, split) AS g
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
            , (usage_till - '2:0'::time)::date
            - (usage_from - '2:0'::time)::date AS split  -- results in integer
      FROM   t
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
```

#### How?

- In the inner subquery `sub1` I find whether the time range crosses 2 a.m. and save that in the column `split`. I am assuming the time range never crosses 2 a.m. twice, but the query could easily be adapted to that. `generate_series()` automatically generates 1 row per wrap around.
- In the next subquery `sub2` `generate_series()` generates two rows where a split is needed.
- In the outer SELECT a CASE statement adjusts the timestamps accordingly.
- Normally I would use `interval '2 hours'` instead of `'2:0'::time`, but I seem to remember Redshift doesn't support the `interval` type.

[**SQL Fiddle** for Postgres 8.3.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/fab34/2)

#### Not in Redshift?

If Redshift only allows `generate_series()` in the `FROM` list and not in the `SELECT` list, you are out of luck. This already is the ancient form. In modern Postgres, you would use a `LATERAL JOIN`. You could try your luck with [regexp_split_to_table()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html), but that's not in Postgres 8.0 either.

[<sup>1</sup> But the manual says, `generate_series()` is **unsupported**.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Barring that, I can only think of a procedural solution with PL/pgSQL. But Redshift might be limited there, too ...

Comment: well appreciated your efforts and the explanation provided. Your example in SQL Fiddle is the perfect; but generate_series(integer,integer) is not supported in PostgreSQL 8.02. So in short my issue remains open.

Comment: Is there any way that we can handle the above solution in PostgreSQL 8.02 ??

Comment: but i can able to execute `SELECT * FROM generate_series(2, 4) ` and `SELECT * FROM generate_series(5,1,-1)` it gives the answer.

Comment: @dhanishjose: Added some more clues. Otherwise I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Is there any chance that I get the actual function code so that I can explicitly create that function and then use in my code?

Comment: @dhanishjose: Can you investigate first whether Redshift allows set-returning functions (a.k.a. "table-functions, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701981/how-to-return-temp-table-from-postgres-function/22703323#22703323)). Because I do not know that.

Comment: in the Amazon Redshift site under list of Unsupported PostgreSQL functions, it is written Set returning functions `GENERATE_SERIES()` and `GENERATE_SUBSCRIPTS()` are not supported.